# Using "rem" combined with "vw" for flexible websites

Tags: css

With the following CSS, I get a precise, proportional scaling layout:

```
html {
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.6rem; // 16px @ 1000px screen width
}

.some-div {
    padding: 2rem; // 20px @ 1000px screen width
}
```

The thing I like about this approach, is that I can maintain a consistent ratio in between media queries. So for example, the result (text, line-breaks/hyphenation, proportions) will look exactly the same on every smartphone, whether it's 480px, 460px or 440px wide.

On larger screens, I simply set the root font-size to a fixed unit, so the UI won't get "too bold" and behaves like a traditional website:

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

No hundreds or thousands lines of "responsive code" required, like you usually see in bootstrap websites and other "traditional workflows".
I even use this approach, if I don't need proportional scaling. Simply because I have it ready to go, when I need it at some point.

But the thing is, I've never seen this in the wild and I'm wondering why?
Are there any flaws with this approach? Why not just use this in general?

Comment: I don't think this is a SO question. I think this will result in opinionated answers

Comment: Facts like, for example, bad performance are not opinion based.

Comment: IMHO, this question is clear and it can be useful. The only drawback is that it may have a definitive answer ("in scenario X it fails because of Y", "it wasn't available in 99% of browsers until year Z") or not. But you can't know if you don't ask.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, it's good. In practice, though, it has at least the following  problems:

- not all fonts look good at all sizes and not all browsers do a good job at approximating them. Most problems appear when elements start being animated and, because of the approximation techniques, text looks blurry while the animation is in progress. What's worse is that animating other elements in the page affects text that is not being animated (shouldn't budge), producing a weird effect. (i.e: text blurs when opening/closing the menu...).
  To work around this problem, some problematic fonts have been optimized for values of `font-size` expressed in `px` (they look good at `15px` and `16px` - not so much at `15.5px`). The blurring effect still happens, but it's not as noticeable at some values.
- this technique needs an exception on narrow mobile devices. One needs to be able to read text even on narrow screens

Other than that, Bootstrap 4 does use `rem` for `padding`. They tried to do it in v3 as well, but reverted due to poor browser support.